# How to get rows with content count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table below

Before

[image]

I need a query which gets  table below

After

[image]

If i use

```
select row_name 
from table_name 
group by row_name
```

it gets unique contents bu i need unique contents with content counts.

Comment: Re-assigning the IDs is a near universally bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `row_number()` & `count()` along with the aggregation :

```
select text, count(*),
       row_number() over (order by text) as id
from table t
group by text;
```